# Install skanect

Tags: 3d, kinect

I'm working on a 3D scan with the kinect, but I can't install the software skanect on ubuntu 16.04. If someone has already done it, I need some help please ^_^.

Thank you!

Comment: The way this q&a works best for you to provide a question with an actual problem, where the preference would be  to show an error message. The way you worded this you will get 1/2 answers, answers providing info you already know, tried and discarded and all that lessens the chance of getting the info you require to install it.

Comment: Related: it seems to require Open NI 2. Did you install that?

Comment: Yes, it's already installed! The problem is that I'm not facing yet any error message! i've downloaded the software for MAC OS X, and I can't find any install file!

Comment: Ubuntu is not MAC OS X. You need a download specifc for linux (and pref. debian based installer)

Comment: Okey, now I see! Thank you for your help :)